# Is it bad for software developers to sign their comments in the code?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, code

I am a software developer and I work in a big team where everybody works on everybody's code.

I am used to comment a lot, indicating what I am editing, why, and what is expected to happen after a snippet of code runs.
I think this is useful becouse when your code gets reviewed or edited by someone else, they can directly ask you for anything they do not understand.

Everybody in the team uses Git, so their edits are tracked through commits and push.

However, when you [**merge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)) somebody's branch with someone else's one, you lose the information of who coded what, and I think this thing leads to the fact that, in the end, some of the reasons that led someone to code some snippet in a certain way are forgotten.
So one goes on coding things in a certain way and only in the end one discovers that it was better to code things in another way, and that someone else already carried an analysis to determine how to do that the best way.

That is the reason why sometimes I feel the need to sign my comments, since I feel this could keep track of my thoughts/analyses/approach, and help who might edit/review that code in the future.

For example, following [Wikipedia community standard syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Signatures#Standard_signature), I would sign my comments with a string indicating the sign element (let's say `~~~~`), then my name, and then date and time.

So for example:

```
# This variable should never get a negative value in scenario1 ~~~~USER1 2022-01-18 15:06
c = data["quantity"]
```

However, I have never seen anybody signing her/his comments in the code.

Is there a good reason not to do it?

Comment: Would this solve your concern? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15769756/1797579

Comment: that's something I would ask my colleagues, or the styleguide document at your company. I understand the intent, but I'm not sure if it clutters the code too much, if every small comment is signed (not to speak of the time it takes to write...).

Comment: There is literally a add-on to most code editors that will automatically tag changed lines with their respected Git comment.

Comment: You should definitely add personal email to that comment along with "will provide unlimited support for this code for free 24/7, death may delay responses". If that does not work for than value of such comments is possibly negative - please make sure to stand behind your comments forever :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Don't do this. This is poor form.

Source control has solved this problem. If people are doing squash merges, they are deliberately discarding this information. That's the thing that you need to fix, if that behaviour isn't wanted.

In addition, what's important is not you, but the context around the change. If you feel inclined to add a reference to something else, you should add a reference to a bug ticket, or some documentation, which is a lot more reliable than trying to track down the user (hopefully they are still employed!) and hope they remember the context.

Comment: I disagree.  Header comments for a changed component shoud tell us who write it right there instead of forcing us to look into the repository to figure it out.

Comment: @TigerGuy My 95% usecase is I want to actually see what those changes are when I spot an "interesting" commit. Maybe get a (better) IDE if you find this laborious.

Comment: In IntelliJ , for instance, it can be a single key-binding to bring up `git blame` with name, date and commit-id against each line. You can then use the same key-binding to make it go away again and have the screen real-estate back. You don't really have to look into the repository

Comment: This used to be the style where I work, a long long time ago, before version control. Every line had a name at the end of it if you edited it. Thankfully they stopped doing this, over 20 years ago, with the advent of version control. Same as any comments in the header of a file with version control information it it.